# c# take N result from IReadOnlyCollection base on condition

Tags: c#, generics

So i have function that return `IReadOnlyCollection<object>`

```
IReadOnlyCollection<object> calc = GetAll();
```

Inside this `calc` i have Dictionary of `string, object`, so when i want to search some `value` based on some `Key`:

```
foreach (var item in calc)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> t= (Dictionary<string, object>)item;
    var id = t.First(x => x.Key == "MyKey").Value.ToString();    
}
```

But this i get inside this `foreach` loop.

Any case of doing this without any `Loop` ? (in case for example i want to take `N` results) ?

Comment: Can you please add some context? It's not clear from the question what exactly you are trying to achieve. "Take `N` results"... results of what? dictionaries from `calc`, or `Value`s of "MyKey"...what keeps you from strongly typing the dictionaries and the read-only-collection (why isn't it a `IReadOnlyCollection<Dictionary<string,string>>`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to all values of "MyKey" entries in all dictionaries in `calc`, you can do it like that:

```
var ids = calc.OfType<Dictionary<string,object>>()             // get all dictionaries
              .SelectMany(d => d.Where(x => x.Key == "MyKey")) // get all KeyValuePairs with a key "MyKey"
              .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())                 // get the values as string
              .ToList();                                       // make it a list
```

This results in a `List<string>`.

If you want only `N` results use `Take()`:

```
var ids = calc.OfType<Dictionary<string,object>>()             // get all dictionaries
              .SelectMany(d => d.Where(x => x.Key == "MyKey")) // get all KeyValuePairs with a key "MyKey"
              .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())                 // get the values as string
              .Take(N)                                         // take only first N values
              .ToList();                                       // make it a list
```